# "Рубль-Два". Какой вид связи?

Tags: синтаксис

"Рубль-Два". Какой вид грамматической связи?

Answer (score 5):

**Скорее всего, это сочинительная связь.** "Рубль-два" —  это дефисная запись сочетания "**один или два рубля**", что соответствует **сочинительной (соединительной**) связи.

[**Розенталь: § 8. Соединительное тире**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=95#pp95)

3) Тире ставится для обозначения количественных пределов: Рукопись объёмом десять — двенадцать авторских листов (то же цифрами: 10 — 12); Груз массой 300 — 350 тонн; 5 — 7-кратное превосходство.

Примечание. Если между двумя рядом стоящими числительными можно вставить не слова **от…до**, а слово **или**, то числительные соединяются **дефисом**: Пробудет в командировке **пять-шесть дней** (но при цифровом обозначении ставится тире: …5 — 6 дней).

Примечание. Сочинительная связь используется для связи однородных членов.